# How can I put the sticky menu on top of the slider

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, slider, z-index

My sticky menu doesnt show on top of the slider iv tried to put z-index on the slider and menu but it doesnt work :( in chrome - in firefox it works.

How can I let this work?
This is my website: http://crepes.salescaredev.nl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple sticky menu bar on top of window check this URL it might help

http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/6-navigation-menu-that-stays-on-top-with-jquery